# How to extract contents after the last slash in fields in splunk?

Tags: splunk, rex

I am new to splunk..SO i have a log which has contents(events) in this format

tool_code: error_code (path1/path2/path3/filename1,line) path1.path2.path3.testname1

I wrote rex to extract filenames and testnames
rex is

```
|rex field=_raw (?<UNW>\S+)\s+(?<UNWA>\S+)\s+(?<FILE_NAME>\S+)\s+(?<TEST_NAME>\S+)
```

this created  table of this format (by using this command`|table FILE_NAME, TEST_NAME`)

FILE_NAME                            --------------------------------------                TEST_NAME

path1/path2/path3/filename1,line    ------------                 path1.path2.path3.testname1

but i want FILE_NAME to hold only the name(filename1) and not the path(we should extract the contents before the last slash and after the comma) and similarly TEST_NAME should only have testname1 and not the path.

kindly help me in achieving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a field that is called "FILE_NAME".
What you can do now, is make a new field using the split command:

```
   `eval OnlyFileName = mvindex(split(FILE_NAME,"/"),-1)`
```

eval = make new field

mvindex(split = the split command

"/" = split by /

-1 = the last object in list.

continue spliting until you get what you want.

I recommend using this way which is much simpler than using regex all the time. takes much less time...

Comment: This partly works...the thing is I'm getting filename1,line
How can I strip of the contents after comma ...

Comment: Very simple, you split again, only this time you change the "/" into ",", and chane -1 into 0.

should look like: ```eval ReallyOnlyFileName = mvindex(split(OnlyFileName,","),0)```

Comment: Thank you so much for the Help!! I have been struggling with this for a long time...

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression.

```
| rex "[\S\/]+\/(?<FILE_NAME>\S+),\w+\)\s+[\S\.]+\.(?<TEST_NAME>\w+)$"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in a couple distinct steps:

```
| rex field=_raw ":\s+error_code\W+(?<full_path>[^,]+),(?<line>[^)]+)\W+(?<test_path>.+)"
```

Followed by:

```
| rex field=full_path "(?<filename>\w+)$"
```

Followed by:

```
| rex field=test_path "(?<testname>[^\.]+)$"
```

Presuming, of course, there are no dots in the "testname" - this will work :)